# Why are component children included under props `this.props.children` and not directly as `this.children`?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and it seems to me that children components are distinct from props. From a framework design perspective, is there an advantage to having children included among `this.props`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple advantages.

1. It keeps everything that the component receives under `props`. This is a cognitive load issue; anything send to a component that is defined by its parent's `render` function (or a `DOM.render`) is on the same property: `props`.
2. It makes comparisons in `componentWillReceiveProps` simpler, since changing `props.children` is not a change to `state`, but will result in a component re-rendering. Having to look at `newProps` *and some other property* could easily confuse developers, and stops simple property enumeration, like `for...of` loops from picking up the change.
3. It reduces the component api. If `this.children` was used, it is one more property that the component cannot use for itself. Putting it under `props.children` means only the lifecycle methods, `props`, `setState` and `state` are taken by the api.